# How to pass a Swift string to a c function?

Tags: c, xcode, swift, input-parameters

I am having serious trouble passing a string from swift, to a function written in c.

I'm trying to do this in my swift code

```
var address = "192.168.1.2"
var port = 8888

initSocket(address, port)
```

The c function looks like this:

```
void initSocket(char *address, int port);
```

Im getting the error:
Cannot convert the expression's of type 'Void' to type 'CMutablePointer'

I can't seem to find a solution that works.

Comment: I think if you had `const char*` argument on C side it would work seamlessly.

Comment: Wojtek you are my hero! Thank you so much..

Solution: Changed c function to `initSocket(const char* address)` and string declaration to `var address: CString = "192.168.1.2"

Thanks again!

Comment: @WojtekSurowka, Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: I think you should rewrite your comment as an answer so that it can be marked as the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift CStrings work seamlessly with C constant strings, so use

```
void initSocket(const char *address, int port);
```

instead of `char*` argument, and declare your `address` variable as CString:

```
var address: CString = "192.168.1.2";
```

Comment: You may want to update that question. With Swift 2.2 or newer, Swift strings are not automatically bridged to C strings. C strings are now `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` and Swift strings can automatically bridge to that. The type `CString` has been removed from the language.

Answer (score 2):

in C, declare your parameter like this

```
void setLastName(const char* lastName){

}
```

then in swift, you can directly pass in a regular swift string

```
setLastName("Montego");
```

the key is to define the variable with the asterisk  immediately after the char in C like: `const char*`

source: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6