# Passing a Swift string to C

Tags: ios, c, swift

I am pretty new to Swift, and I don't have much exposure to C.

I am trying to write a function in C that will get a Swift string that I can then do something with. The problem is that I'm not 100% sure what the type should be in Swift to make C like what it sees.

So far, I have found several examples on Stack that seem like good starting points, but some examples seem dated for the current version of Swift.

I first started by using this example to get C and Swift talking to one another: [Swift call C call Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672263/swift-call-c-call-swift) I then took that and tried updating the Swift function to return a string of some kind. I understand that it needs to be a UTF-8 return type, but I'm not sure how to go about sending things properly. I've looked at [How to pass a Swift string to a c function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378954/how-to-pass-a-swift-string-to-a-c-function), [How to convert String to UnsafePointer<UInt8> and length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554986/how-to-convert-string-to-unsafepointeruint8-and-length), and [How to convert string to unicode(UTF-8) string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087325/how-to-convert-string-to-unicodeutf-8-string-in-swift), but none of them really work for a solution. Or I'm just typing it in incorrectly. So far, the closest I can get to returning something is as follows.

In Swift, my `ViewController` is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @_silgen_name("mySwiftFunc") // give the function a C name
    public func mySwiftFunc(number: Int) -> [CChar]
    {
        print("Hello from Swift: \(number)")

        let address: String = "hello there";
        let newString = address.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return newString!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        blah()

    }
}
```

And in C, the header is like:

```
#ifndef cfile_h
#define cfile_h

#include <stdio.h>

const char * mySwiftFunc(int);
int blah(void);

#endif /* cfile_h */
```

And the source is like:

```
#include "cfile.h"

int blah() {

    const char * retVal = mySwiftFunc(42); // call swift function
    printf("Hello from C: %s", retVal);

    return 0;
}
```

There is a bridging header file that just has `#include "cfile.h"`. Obviously, there is still a lot of remnants from the first example, and these will be cleaned up later.

What needs to change to make this work? Right now, the console spits out

```
Hello from Swift: 42
Hello from C: (B\214
```

Comment: I don't have time to look into this right now, but I just have to say that this is a really well written question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Swift equivalent of `const char *` is `UnsafePointer<CChar>?`, so that's the correct return value. Then you have to think about memory management. One options is do allocate memory for the C string in the Swift function, and leave it to the caller to release the memory eventually:

```
public func mySwiftFunc(number: Int) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>? {
    print("Hello from Swift: \(number)")

    let address = "hello there"
    let newString = strdup(address)
    return UnsafePointer(newString)
}
```

passes a Swift string to `strdup()` so that a (temporary) C string representation is created automatically. This C string is then duplicated. The calling C function has to release that memory when it is no longer needed:

```
int blah() {
    const char *retVal = mySwiftFunc(42);
    printf("Hello from C: %s\n", retVal);
    free((char *)retVal);
    return 0;
}
```

**⚠️  BUT:** Please note that there are more problems in your code:

- `mySwiftFunc()` is an *instance method* of a class, and therefore has an implicit `self` argument, which is ignored by the calling C function. That might work by chance, or cause strange failures.
- `@_silgen_name` should not be used outside of the Swift standard library, see [this discusssion](https://forums.swift.org/t/should-anyone-be-using-silgen-name-outside-of-the-standard-library-developers/19396) in the Swift forum.
- A slightly better alternative is `@_cdecl` but even that is not officially supported. `@_cdecl` can only be used with global functions.
- Generally, calling Swift functions directly from C is *not officially supported,* see [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/best-way-to-call-a-swift-function-from-c/9829) in the Swift forum for the reasons and possible alternatives.